# How to play chess against a large number of players simultaneously?

Tags: chess-variants, simultaneous

Lately, we have done an experiment in our chess club and liked it much. We were 4 players, and we wanted to play simultaneous each against each other. This setup worked (more or less, see the following diagram):

[image]

The players 1, 2, and 3 may sit on their tables, but the player 4 (myself) had to walk around from board to board (identified by `Pl4`).

Then a 5th player came around, and we could not find a reasonable setup where we can play and know who is playing where.

Is this a known problem, and for how many are solutions known? For 2, 3, and 4, it is easy, but how about higher numbers?

Comment: It isn't quite the same thing, but check out a variant called "bughouse". Tons of fun!

Comment: We play that a lot (at least with the younger players). In Germany known as "Tandem". From time to time, we test some variations we don't know. My favorite one: Hand and Brain. 2x2 players, one players says first e.g. pawn, the other player has to move a pawn. No tips allowed. With time control, you need some more time (> 10 minutes). Lots of fun!

Comment: This is a really interesting question, I'd like to know the answer myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some ideas that might help!
[image]

Comment: Very nice! Do you have some background for that, or did you just made it up for your own? Where do we get so many small tables for the setup?

Comment: @mliebelt Thanks! I made it on my own! The question was quite interesting, so I took the challenge! For playing in 4, I think you can still use the 3 tables you showed in your picture, but make a triangle and one plays in the middle, if it is not too far for the others. The small tables help to have a closer layout, such as those square ones from schools, enough to have a board on it! Cheers!